# MongoDB C# driver - Serialize collection to interface

Tags: c#, mongodb, interface, mongodb-.net-driver, event-sourcing

Due to environment restrictions at work I'm implementing a rough Event Sourcing store in MongoDB. I'm trying to get a list of `IClientEvents` from Mongo like so:

```
 var events = await _db.GetCollection<IClientEvent>("ClientEvents").FindAsync(c => c.ClientId == clientId);
```

I get the following exception when I run the above mentioned repository method:

```
Message: System.InvalidOperationException : {document}.ClientId is not supported.
```

The `IClientEvent` interface is defined as:

```
public interface IClientEvent
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    long TimeStamp { get; set; }
    Guid ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class ClientChangedEvent : IClientEvent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Change> Changes;
    // ... other properties for the event
}
```

There will be many different event types stored into a single collection, all of which will implement `IClientEvent`. I want to just get, in a single call, all events that have occurred to a Client by `clientId`.

I have registered all of the concrete implementations of `IClientEvent` and even added a custom discriminator:

```
        var clientEventsDiscriminator = new ClientEventsMongoDiscriminatorConvention();
        BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(IClientEvent),clientEventsDiscriminator);
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ClientChangedEvent>();
        BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(ClientChangedEvent), clientEventsDiscriminator);
```

I have even tried registering an `ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer` as mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435760/how-to-fix-document-id-is-not-supported-error) but it throws an exception when I register the 2nd concrete implementation that I have already registered a serializer for `IClientEvent`.

Not sure where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

-- EDIT for more code:

Here is the full registration code:

```
        var clientEventsDiscriminator = new ClientEventsMongoDiscriminatorConvention();
        BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(IClientEvent),clientEventsDiscriminator);

        clientEventsDiscriminator.AddEventType<ClientChangedEvent>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ClientChangedEvent>();
        BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(ClientChangedEvent), clientEventsDiscriminator);

        clientEventsDiscriminator.AddEventType<ClientAddedEvent>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ClientAddedEvent>();
        BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(ClientAddedEvent), clientEventsDiscriminator);
```

Here is the Discriminator:

```
    public class ClientEventsMongoDiscriminatorConvention : IDiscriminatorConvention
{
    private Dictionary<string, Type> _eventTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public string ElementName => "_eventType";

    public BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
    {
        return GetDiscriminatorValueForEventType(actualType);
    }

    public Type GetActualType(IBsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType)
    {
        var bookmark = bsonReader.GetBookmark();
        bsonReader.ReadStartDocument();
        if (!bsonReader.FindElement(ElementName))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Unable to find property '{ElementName}' in document. Cannot map to an EventType.");
        }

        var value = bsonReader.ReadString();
        bsonReader.ReturnToBookmark(bookmark);

        if (_eventTypes.TryGetValue(value, out var type))
        {
            return type;
        }

        throw new InvalidCastException($"The type '{value}' has not been registered with the '{nameof(ClientEventsMongoDiscriminatorConvention)}'.");
    }

    private string GetDiscriminatorValueForEventType(Type type)
    {
        var indexOfEventWord = type.Name.IndexOf("Event");
        if (indexOfEventWord == -1)
        {
            return type.Name;
        }
        return type.Name.Substring(0, indexOfEventWord);
    }

    public void AddEventType<T>()
    {
        var discriminatorName = GetDiscriminatorValueForEventType(typeof(T));
        _eventTypes.TryAdd(discriminatorName, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

When running the code it doesn't appear to ever hit the `GetActualType` method of the discriminator.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to provide the concrete type to that repository method?  How is the repository method supposed to know that `ClientChangedEvent` is the implementation you want?

Comment: And it's unclear from your question whether `ClientEventsMongoDiscriminatorConvention` provides the requisite mapping.  You haven't shown us that code.

Comment: Try making the interface properties public.

Comment: Hey @RobertHarvey - I have edited the question with the code you requested. As noted - it doesn't look like the `GetActualType` meothod of the discriminator ever gets hit when running the code.

Comment: @jdweng - it is not legal to decorate interface properties/methods with public/private/etc. It is implied to be public.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - as far as adding a concrete type to the method that is not what I want. I want to get all events for a Client regardless of type. I'd expect the discriminator to tell the serializer which concrete class to serialize it to (which you can now see in the code I added)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by simply changing `IClientEvent` from an interface to an abstract class.