# MongoDb.DeleteMany InvalidOperationException: {document}.LikedElement is not supported

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have interface `ILike` for entity `Like`.

ILike interface

```cs
public interface ILike
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string LikedElement { get; set; }
}
```

Like implementation

```cs
public class Like : ILike
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault(true)]
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string LikedElement { get; set; }
}
```

And Mongo `BsonDocument`

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d9aed72e5da393f449f6cfc"),
    "_t": "Like",
    "LikedElement": ObjectId("5d99dabcd2372b3431da7bae")
}
```

And when I try use like this

```cs
private void DeleteRelatedLikes(string targetEntityId)
{
    dataContext.LikeGateway.DeleteMany(record => record.LikedElement == targetEntityId);
}
// TEntity is ILike
public void DeleteMany(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
{
    mongoCollection.DeleteMany(filter);
}
```

where mongoCollection is

```cs
private readonly IMongoCollection<ILike> mongoCollection;
```

mongo driver throw exception `InvalidOperationException: {document}.LikesElement is not support`.
But all worked when mongoCollections is

```cs
private readonly IMongoCollection<Like> mongoCollection;
```

What should I do? I can`t use class instead interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435760/how-to-fix-document-id-is-not-supported-error)

If you don't want to use `BsonSerializerAttribute`, you can use this code **before initializing MongoClient instance.**

```cs
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer<IEntity>(
    new ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer<IEntity, Entity>());
```